# Story in which a textile robot developed artificial intelligence

Tags: story-identification

Many, many years ago I remember reading sci fi story in which one of the characters was a sentient robot who, if I recall the story correctly, was originally some sort of textile robot in factory. It was designed with excellent pattern recognition skills due to the nature of the job, and eventually developed true intelligence. I think the robot may have served as some sort of guide/guardian to the human characters in the story, but that's about the limit of my recollection.

Does that ring a bell with anyone?

Comment: Interesting in that it seems to echo the very first thing that was a precursor of AI -- the Jacquard Loom. Surely some people imagined that these looms had intelligence since they had so little experience with technology and even if their imaginings were wrong they were on the right track.

Comment: Was this a short story, or was it novel length?

Comment: I believe it was a novel.